# Is there a requirement to explicitly call out a preferred embodiment?

Tags: drafting, embodiments

In a patent application, is it acceptable to mention several potential embodiments, and say you don't know which one is preferred? Or should you just mention the one that you have implemented?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/can-a-patent-have-more-than-one-multiple-preferred-embodiments (by same asker).

Comment: I would suggest the preferred embodiments and all the others the are meaningful - this way you create prior art that will also allow you to do developments in case you are not protect with a claim, but you will not be limited by someone filing a different embodiment.

Answer (score 1):

You must describe the preferred embodiment, but you do not need to state which of several embodiments is the preferred one.